# bottom alignment of two side-by-side wellpanels in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, alignment, fluid-layout

I'm trying to code a shiny layout with 2 horizontal well Panels, one on the right one on the left, but the one on the right should be composed of 2 vertical well Panels itself.

I can't make them align at the bottom. Is that possible? 
My simplified app below. I tried to add a fluidrow to put them both, but it doesn't change anything.

```
ui <- tagList( navbarPage(id="navbar", title="title",
                          tabPanel(title="Home",
                                   titlePanel(title="Welcome"),
                                   column(6,
                                          wellPanel(
                                               h2("Hello World"),
                                               br(),
                                               h4("some text"))),
                                   column(6,
                                          fluidRow(
                                               wellPanel(
                                                    h2("News"),
                                                    br(),
                                                    h4("Some other text"),
                                                    br(),
                                                    fluidRow(column(6, 
                                                                    h5("Some info:")),
                                                             column(6, 
                                                                    div(actionButton("button", "button"), style="float:right") 
                                                             )))),
                                          fluidRow(
                                               wellPanel(div(img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", width=100), style="text-align: center;")
                                               )))),
                          tabPanel(title="anothertabl", value="anothertabl"))
)
server=function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It should look like this, with both wellPanels automatically adapting to the longest one
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get the solution above to work for my use case, but got it working by manually specifying the same height for each wellPanel. It might not be ideal to hardcode the heights in every case, but it's a simple solution that would often work just fine. For example:

```
fluidRow(
  column(width = 3, offset = 3,
         wellPanel(style = "height:150px",
                   "wellPanel1 content")),
  column(width = 3,
         wellPanel(style = "height:150px", 
                   "wellPanel2 content"))
)
```

Comment: A `wellPanel` height can also be defined in `em` (rather than `px`)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really simple.

I added a `row` around the columns that I cave `postion:relative`. then I made the first shorter column `position:absolute` and set it to span the whole heigth with `top:0;bottom:0;left:0;`. since the first column has position `absolute` we must add an `offset = 6` to the second column, otherwise would both columns be placed on top of each other.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- tagList( navbarPage(id="navbar", title="title",
                          tabPanel(title="Home",
                                   titlePanel(title="Welcome"),
                                   fluidRow(
                                     style = "position:relative",
                                     column(6,
                                            style = "position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;padding-bottom:19px",
                                            wellPanel(
                                              style = "height:100%;",
                                              h2("Hello World"),
                                              br(),
                                              h4("some text"))),
                                     column(6,
                                            fluidRow(
                                              wellPanel(
                                                h2("News"),
                                                br(),
                                                h4("Some other text"),
                                                br(),
                                                fluidRow(column(6, 
                                                                h5("Some info:")),
                                                         column(6, 
                                                                div(actionButton("button", "button"), style="float:right") 
                                                         )))),
                                            fluidRow(
                                              wellPanel(div(img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", width=100), style="text-align: center;")
                                              )),
                                            offset = 6)

                                   )
                                   ),
                          tabPanel(title="anothertabl", value="anothertabl"))
)
server=function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Bertil, thanks for answering again to one of my questions! :-) Your solution works indeed with my simplified code but for some reason it fails with my real app. Guess i oversimplified it. The problem is that because of my images and sliders, when you change the size of the window, it can invert the panel that is the longest one (sometimes the right one, sometiems the left). Complicated..

Comment: Doesn't look good when the fluid row becomes narrow